# Information for ID into SRC of Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, userscripts

I have a user script to add a calculation form to a website. The iframe should pull the price (ID lblFcost) and insert this into the SRC of the iframe for the calculation form.

This is the userscript I have and trialled code.

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById('tblManConNoteMsg');
theDiv.innerHTML = '<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" width="1000" height="1000" src="https://exampleurl.com/tnt-surcharge/?price=" + lblFcost;></iframe>';
```

Glad of any help.

Comment: Are you able to use Jquery or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: Hello @Jay - It is via Userscript on Tampermonkey so can include Jquery yes.